# Json to define linked service for AzureDataLakeAnalytics with servicePrincipal

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a pipeline that invokes an U-SQL transformation.
Deployed the linked services, datasets, pipelines using the portal

The Linked service JSON for ADLS supports ServicePrincipal but for ADLA shows error if I declare servicePrincipalKey.

1. Does the portal support to author linked service for
   "AzureDataLakeAnalytics" or do I need to deploy using VS?
2. Is there a sample?, because the following JSON doesn't work

The following sample shows error:

```
{
"name": "ADLA-ProdLinkService",
"properties": {
    "type": "AzureDataLakeAnalytics",
    "typeProperties": {
        "accountName": "my-account",
        "servicePrincipalId": "my principal id",
        "servicePrincipalKey": {
            "value": "secret key",
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "tenant": "directory id",
        "subscriptionId": "my subscription",
        "resourceGroupName": "my resource"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I was able to trigger USQL scripts using the following linked service

```
{
    "name": "linkedservice-dataanalytics",
    "properties": {
      "type": "AzureDataLakeAnalytics",
      "typeProperties": {
        "accountName": "<name of your analytics account>",
        "subscriptionId": "<subscription id in which ADLA exists>",
        "resourceGroupName": "<resource group name in which ADLA exists>",
        "servicePrincipalId": "<id of app>",
        "servicePrincipalKey": "<key of app>",
        "tenant": "<guid tenant id from the portal>"
      }
    }
}
```

- I ensured that the app id which was included had appropriate access to both Azure Data Lake Store and Azure Data Lake Analytics
- I added the app as the owner of the resource group which contained the analytics account and the data lake store account. however that might too much of an access. you could try a restricted approach.
- Azure Data Factory v1

Answer (score 0):

I found that the portal "squiggle tool tips" as not supported fields for AzureDataLakeAnalytics are not enforced.

This is the URL with the correct format for the Linked Service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-usql-activity

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Azure Data Factory V1 or Azure Data Factory V2? The syntax you are using (servicePrincipalKey in type of secureString) is for ADF V2. Please share detailed error message if you are using V2.

If you are using ADF V1, follow the syntax shared by @frictionlesspulley.